# How to sort an array from an object?

Tags: javascript

How to sort an array from an object ?
The code :

```
         let A = [ { text: '故事', value: 'story', },
                   { text: '诗歌', value: 'poetry', },
                   { text: '励志', value: 'inspirational', }
                 ];
         // array B from backend** 
         let B = { 
                   story: 2,
                   poetry: 34,
                   inspirational: 30,
                 };
```

I want to get this :

```
             [ 
               { text: '诗歌', value: 'poetry', },
               { text: '励志', value: 'inspirational'},
               { text: '故事', value: 'story', }, 
             ];
```

Comment: So you're trying to sort from greatest to smallest based on the value of a property of an object you get?

Comment: `A.sort((a, b) => B[b.value] - B[a.value])` for greatest to smallest

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can use JavaScript [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function.

**Note:** When sorting numbers, you can simply use the compact comparison:

> **Compact Comparison::** myArray.sort((n1,n2) => n1 - n2);

```js
let A = [ { text: '故事', value: 'story', },
                   { text: '诗歌', value: 'poetry', },
                   { text: '励志', value: 'inspirational', }
                 ];
         // array B from backend** 
         let B = { 
                   story: 2,
                   poetry: 34,
                   inspirational: 30,
                 };
 A.sort((a, b) => B[b.value]-B[a.value] );
                 console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an arrow function in `array.sort` as a custom comparator. Sorting in reverse order is accomplished by indexing into the `B` object to retrieve the sort value for compared elements and subtracting `a`'s value from `b`.

```js
let A = [ 
  { text: '故事', value: 'story', },
  { text: '诗歌', value: 'poetry', },
  { text: '励志', value: 'inspirational', }
];
let B = { 
  story: 2,
  poetry: 34,
  inspirational: 30,
};

const sorted = A.sort((a, b) => B[b.value] - B[a.value]);

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sort()` to arrange the array elements. You can use [`Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/NEGATIVE_INFINITY) as a default value if the `value` does not exist on `B`. This will put the undefined value last.

```js
let A = [{"text":"诗歌","value":"poetry"},{"text":"励志","value":"inspirational"},{"text":"故事","value":"story"}];
let B = {"story":2,"poetry":34,"inspirational":30};

A.sort((x, y) => (B[y.value] || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY) - (B[x.value] || Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY));

console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it uses an arrow function and `array.sort`:

```js
let A = [{
    text: '故事',
    value: 'story',
  },
  {
    text: '诗歌',
    value: 'poetry',
  },
  {
    text: '励志',
    value: 'inspirational',
  }
];
// array B from backend** 
let B = {
  story: 2,
  poetry: 34,
  inspirational: 30,
};
A.sort((a, b) => B[b.value] - B[a.value]);
console.log(A);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the function `Array.prototype.sort` you can accomplish your desired output.

This `B[bV] - B[aV]` will return a value lesser than `0` or greater than `0` or equal to `0` which is what the function `sort` is expecting on to locate the elements at the specific index according to their value from object `B`.

```js
let A = [{    text: '故事',    value: 'story',  },  {    text: '诗歌',  value: 'poetry',  },  {    text: '励志',    value: 'inspirational',  }],
    B = {  story: 2,  poetry: 34,  inspirational: 30};
A.sort(({value: aV}, {value: bV}) => B[bV] - B[aV]);

console.log(A);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```